# How to properly move media files and update data?

Tags: uploads, media, attachments

Bashing my head against a wall here.

I want to write a function that **moves** the actual file of a Media Library attachment, but this must necessarily update all metadata.

I am already doing a `foreach` on each attachment I want to move, calling the function...

- `$post_attachment` is an `attachment` object.
- `$existing_path` is the item's existing path, minus the filename (basename) - eg: `Users/robert/Sites/context.local/wp-content/uploads/media/folio/clients/ghost`
- `$preferred_path` is my intended destination for the file - eg. `/Users/robert/Sites/context.local/wp-content/uploads/post/client/ghost`

The function should:

- Create the destination directory if it does not exist.
- Move ALL sizes of images, not just the main/source one.
- Include error handling.
- Update all metadata.
- Frankly, it also needs to update any `<img src>` references in post body content, too. I could either give the function the ID of a specific post object to which it is attached, or it should look for all references in the database, for safety. (This is not yet implemented below).

The code below does successfully move the image file. But it does **not** update the metadata. In the admin, I am looking at a broken image and, after hard-refreshing the page to refresh cache, it's the same.

I notice that the following, at the least, do not change after the function is run:

- the images' `guid` in the post table
- the `meta_value`s of `meta_key`s `_wp_attached_file` and `_wp_attachment_metadata` (weird serialised JSON array?) in the `post_meta` table

**What is the correct way to do this?**

```php
function move_attachment_file($post_attachment, $existing_path, $preferred_path) {

    // Get the attachment ID
    $attachment_id = $post_attachment->ID;

    // Get the file paths of all sizes of the attachment
    $file_paths = array();
    $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id);
    $file_paths[] = get_attached_file($attachment_id);
    foreach ($metadata['sizes'] as $size_info) {
        $file_paths[] = $existing_path . '/' . $size_info['file'];
    }

    // Define the new file paths
    $new_file_paths = array();
    $new_file_paths[] = $preferred_path . '/' . basename($file_paths[0]);
    foreach (array_slice($file_paths, 1) as $size_file_path) {
        $new_file_paths[] = preg_replace(
            '#' . preg_quote($existing_path, '#') . '#',
            $preferred_path,
            $size_file_path
        );
    }

    // Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!file_exists(dirname($new_file_paths[0]))) {
        mkdir(dirname($new_file_paths[0]), 0755, true);
    }

    // Move the files
    $errors = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_paths); $i++) {
        if (!rename($file_paths[$i], $new_file_paths[$i])) {
            $errors[] = "Error moving file " . $file_paths[$i] . " to " . $new_file_paths[$i];
        }
    }

    // Update attachment metadata
    foreach ($metadata['sizes'] as &$size_info) {
        $size_info['file'] = basename($new_file_paths[array_search($existing_path . '/' . $size_info['file'], $file_paths)]);
    }
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $metadata);

    // Update image URLs in post content
    global $wpdb;
    $old_url = str_replace(site_url(), '', wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id));
    $new_url = str_replace(site_url(), '', wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id, 'full'));
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, %s, %s) WHERE post_content LIKE %s", $old_url, $new_url, "%" . $old_url . "%"));

    // Handle errors
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        return new WP_Error('file_move_error', implode("\n", $errors));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to move the attachment file on the disk? And how/where/when are you using the `move_attachment_file` function in the question? Also the last bullet point about changing post content is a much larger task than the rest of your question combined as it requires special consideration or it will fall over on anything but the smallest of sites and fail

Comment: 1. My Media Library contains 3Gb of files attached to work over a 20-year career. WP’s default foldering choice is painful for managing this. In truth, many of the files are better handled in batches of kinds other than date, which works both be more meaningful, would allow better management and potentially expert to future systems.

Comment: you're trying to shard it to distribute over multiple storage devices? 3GB isn't much for most basic hosting solutions, a $5pm digital ocean droplet handles that trivially

Comment: 2. I am developing a plug-in to force storage of media files in folders that mirror the structure of actual content, not dates, and not just all swimming in /uploads. This means using post type names and taxonomy and term names as sub-folders, potentially also with their own date folders inside them. I have built the admin options UI and settings database table for this - for specifying and retrieving my preferred folder path (which happens to be a combination of post_type name, taxonomy name and the term name slug).

Comment: The actual _moving_ should occur in two ways: 1. When I press a button, move the file of every media item attached to a post; thus, tidying up the whole archive. 2. On every future save_post hook event, ie automatically for all future post-images.

I'm starting by building it out via a function that fires on save_hook. So, long story short, it fires as a consequence of save_post.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks, but disk space is not the only consideration. I'm looking to learn how to tackle the task of moving the files as described.